# Read two numbers. Find their product after exchanging last digits

Tags: r

Read two numbers. Find their product after exchanging last digits.
For example: Input: 4270 and 153, output: 640950 (4273x150).
Input: 348 and 31, output: 12958 (341*38).

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

```
x <- 348
y <- 31

as.integer(paste0(x %/% 10, y %% 10)) * as.integer(paste0(y %/% 10, x %% 10))

# [1] 12958
```

also works vecorized

```
x <- c(348, 4270)
y <- c(31, 153)

as.integer(paste0(x %/% 10, y %% 10)) * as.integer(paste0(y %/% 10, x %% 10))

# [1]  12958 640950
```